# Angular 12 ui not updating like I would expect

Tags: angular

I have an angular 12 app I'm working on and the ui is not updating like I would expect it to. After I remove a row from a table the ui doesn't refresh. If I try calling `changedetectorref.detectChanges()` it will update but I don't feel like I should need to do that. I didn't have to do that in previous apps I've worked on. Below is my code.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let provider of providers">
      <td>{{ provider.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <i class="feather icon-edit"></i>
        <i class="feather icon-trash" (click)="delete(provider)"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '@app/shared/services/data.service';
import { Provider } from '@app/shared/types/provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-provider',
  templateUrl: './provider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./provider.component.css']
})
export class ProviderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() providers: Provider[]
  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  delete(provider) {
    this.dataService.deleteStatus(provider).subscribe(result => {
      if(result.status) {
        let index = this.providers.indexOf(provider);
        console.log(index);
        this.providers.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(this.providers);
      }
    });

  }
```

if I push a new provider into `this.providers` outside of the subscribe then it will update the ui. So my guess is it has something do with the subscribe of the data service. Any input or insight is greatly appreciated.

Edit: The other thing of note, is that after the first delete call, any additional call will update the ui.

I've also moved the delete event to the parent component and the same thing still happens where the UI isn't updated.

Comment: Angular does shallow change detect, so removing an element from an existing array does not trigger change detection. Replace the existing array using `Array.splice` or the spread operator instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should not be manipulating a property that is provided via the @Input() decorator. Angular is expecting this property to only change via the @Input() functionality. Realistically, you should move the delete to the parent component and use an event emitter to communicate that it needs to change. This example probably won't work entirely, but it should get you started down the correct path:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '@app/shared/services/data.service';
import { Provider } from '@app/shared/types/provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-provider',
  templateUrl: './provider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./provider.component.css']
})
export class ProviderComponent {

  @Input() providers: Provider[]

  @Output() onDeleteProvider = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor() { }

  // get the index from ngFor in HTML, see below
  delete(index: number) {
    this.onDeleteProvider.emit(index);
  }
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let provider of providers; let i = index;">
      <td>{{ provider.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <i class="feather icon-edit"></i>
        <i class="feather icon-trash" (click)="delete(i)"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
// parent component
export class ParentComponent {
 
  onDelete(index: number) {
    // call the service to delete the provider
  }
}
```

```html
<app-provider [providers]="provdiers" (onDeleteProvider)="onDelete($event)"></app-provider>
```

------- EDIT ------------ 
In addition to this, you should be handling ChangeDetection correctly. If you're using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, you need to make sure you're not mutating the @Input() arguments. Immutable objects only for @Input props on ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Comment: I actually did that as well before anyone answered, but the same thing is still occurring.

Comment: @user3064073 - do you have change detection set to OnPush by chance? It could be an immutability problem if so

Comment: that is what it was, the theme I was using had that on the main layout component. I removed it and it works like a charm. If you change this to an answer I will accept it.